# Mock Time.now with mocha

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, time, mocking, ruby-mocha

To mock `Time.now` with the [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) gem I use the following oneliner.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'                          
require 'mocha/mini_test'                                                                           
require 'time'                                      

class TimeMockTest < Minitest::Test                 
  def test_time_mock       
    # Mocking Time.now in one line                         
    Time.expects(:now).returns(Time.parse('20:12'))

    Time.now                                        
  end                                               
end
```

But running this code returns the following error since `Time.parse()` uses the the mocked `Time.now()` method.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/time.rb:255:in `make_time'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/time.rb:364:in `parse'
    time_mock.rb:8:in `test_time_mock'
```

How do you mock Time.now with `mocha`?

Answer (score 1):

You should check https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop.
It will help you to handle Time in your tests.